# what is the right way to back-up a substrate basepath?

Tags: amazon-s3, substrate

can anyone point me at best-practice guidance for substrate basepath backup and restore? specifically, i'm wondering about these things:

1. it's my experience that backing up the basepath while the substrate service is running, results in a corrupt database that cannot be used in a restore. is that expected? it's not all that surprising if so.

   syncing while the node service is running produces errors and warnings (in the sync process) like this:

   ```
   warning: Skipping file /var/lib/substrate/polkadot/chains/ksmcc3/db/full/642785.sst. File does not exist.
   ```

   and

   ```
   upload failed: ../../var/lib/substrate/polkadot/chains/ksmcc3/db/full/642836.sst to s3://calamari-kusama-smoothie-calamari-systems/var/lib/substrate/polkadot/chains/ksmcc3/db/full/642836.sst [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/lib/substrate/polkadot/chains/ksmcc3/db/full/642836.sst'
   ```

   a basepath restored from a backup taken while the node service was running, always errors (for me) like so:

   ```
   Error: Service(Client(Backend("Invalid argument: Column families not opened: col11, col10, col9, col8, col7, col6, col5, col4, col3, col2, col1, col0")))
   ```

   or:

   ```
   Error: Service(Client(Backend("IO error: No such file or directory: While opening a file for sequentially reading: /var/lib/substrate/chains/calamari/db/full/MANIFEST-009085: No such file or directory")))
   ```
2. is rsyncing the basepath the right way to go about doing backups? for ec2 nodes, i currently sync to an s3 bucket like so (the exclusions omit node key files from the backup):

   ```
   para=calamari
   relay=ksmcc3
   bucket=${para}-${relay}-${HOSTNAME//./-}
   basepath=/var/lib/substrate
   sudo systemctl stop ${para}.service
   /usr/bin/aws s3 sync ${basepath} s3://${bucket}${basepath} \
     --exclude "chains/${para}/network/*" \
     --exclude "polkadot/chains/${relay}/network/*"
   ```
3. which files in the basepath are useful for a restore and should be backed up? as well as the block numbered *.sst and *.log files, this is what i see (on a recently started, still syncing node):

   ```
   $ ls -hl --ignore *.sst --ignore *.log /var/lib/substrate/{polkadot/chains/${relay}/db/{full,full/parachains/db},chains/${para}/db/full/}
   /var/lib/substrate/chains/calamari/db/full/:
   total 23M
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16 Nov 15 17:13 CURRENT
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   37 Nov 15 16:50 IDENTITY
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 15 16:50 LOCK
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  21M Nov 16 06:33 LOG
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.5M Nov 16 06:23 MANIFEST-002019
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48K Nov 15 17:13 OPTIONS-001991
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48K Nov 15 17:13 OPTIONS-002022
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Nov 15 17:13 db_version

   /var/lib/substrate/polkadot/chains/ksmcc3/db/full:
   total 1.4G
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16 Nov 15 17:13 CURRENT
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   37 Nov 15 16:50 IDENTITY
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 15 16:50 LOCK
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.4G Nov 16 06:35 LOG
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  74M Nov 16 06:35 MANIFEST-008095
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48K Nov 15 17:13 OPTIONS-007788
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  48K Nov 15 17:13 OPTIONS-008098
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Nov 15 17:13 db_version
   drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4.0K Nov 15 16:50 parachains
   drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4.0K Nov 15 17:13 pvf-artifacts

   /var/lib/substrate/polkadot/chains/ksmcc3/db/full/parachains/db:
   total 2.1M
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   16 Nov 15 17:13 CURRENT
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root   37 Nov 15 16:50 IDENTITY
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    0 Nov 15 16:50 LOCK
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2.1M Nov 16 06:33 LOG
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  437 Nov 15 17:13 MANIFEST-000033
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24K Nov 15 17:13 OPTIONS-000031
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root  24K Nov 15 17:13 OPTIONS-000036
   -rw-r--r-- 1 root root    1 Nov 15 17:13 parachain_db_version
   ```

Comment: I am asking for a more formal answer from node devops people for you :) -- one ***key*** consideration is the keys! These are very sensitive and in your base path and *NOT* encrypted - be sure you know what you are backing up (and not expicitly) and the possible effects of them being compromised!

Comment: good point @NukeManDan. these nodes are archive nodes and as such have empty key-stores. there are a pair of node keys (one for relay, one for para) but we filter them out in the s3 sync. i suppose i should also filter out the key store in case somebody copy/pastes my sync command one day and spills a key...

Answer (score 1):

Here are so pro tips around doing any kind of DB snapshots:

1. *Always* stop the node before backing up! Failing to do this will usually result in a corrupted DB.
2. Always **exclude** `{basepath}/keystore` and `{basepath}/network` from your backups or only ever explicitly backup `{basepath}/`
3. The entire db folder should be backed up. This can be `rsynced` directly but it can also be `tar`'d or compressed then backed up.